# SASS @import multiple files depending on screen size

Tags: css, import, sass, media-queries

I have in my project over 20 .scss sheets.

I want to put them in an 'imports' sheet where certain sheets are only read depending on screen width.

I have this working in a non-SASS project with an imports.css using the following:

```
@import url('sheet-1.css');

@import url('sheet-2.css') screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 730px);
```

I've tried this in an imports.scss file - but the compiled imports.css has errors saying:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"sheet-2.css') \": expected selector or at-rule, was \"screen and (min...\"\A
```

Is this the wrong approach ? .. or is there a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in the Sass parser when you use `url()`.  You'll want to write it like this instead:

```
@import 'sheet-1.css';
@import 'sheet-2.css' screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 730px);
```

This should compile to (the CSS validator says this is valid):

```
@import url(sheet-1.css);
@import 'sheet-2.css' screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 730px);
```

I've submitted a bug report on your behalf, which you can track here:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1042

I do, however, recommend that you convert these files to Sass so that they are compiled into a single CSS file.  All browsers download all linked stylesheets, even if they don't currently meet the media query restrictions:

```
@import 'sheet-1'; // filename = _sheet-1.scss
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 730px) {
    @import 'sheet-2'; // filename = _sheet-2.scss
}
```

Comment: Can I get the structure straight then   .. sass dir --   sheet1.scss   sheet2.scss   imports.scss (which contains your corrected code above)    css dir -- sheet1.css   sheet2.css   imports.css (compiled by imports.scss)     Is that correct? (sorry formatting here is wrong)

Comment: Please amend your question rather than try to put the code in a comment, it just makes it hard to read this way.  I've amended my answer to show the preferred way of performing imports with Sass.